# Trying to separate a FULL_NAME into FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME in Oracle SQL, but it does not show any changes on the table itself

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This code is supposed to separate full name and it does. This code works fine, except for the fact that it does not add the data to the table.

```
SELECT FULL_NAME
SUBSTR(FULL_NAME, 1, INSTR(FULL_NAME, ' ', 1, 1)-1) as FIRST_NAME,
SUBSTR(FULL_NAME, INSTR(FULL_NAME, ' ', -1)+1) as LAST_NAME
from customers;
```

This code runs similarly but again, does not populate the table.

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS;

SELECT
    substr("A1"."FULL_NAME", 1, instr("A1"."FULL_NAME", ' ', 1, 1) - 1)                 "FIRST_NAME",
    substr("A1"."FULL_NAME", instr("A1"."FULL_NAME", ' ',(- 1)) + 1)                    "LAST_NAME"
FROM
    "XXXX"."CUSTOMERS" "A1";
```

[This is what my query result is, it shows that everything is how it should be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjwkP.png)

[This is what my table looks like but as you can see, the last two columns do not have any data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us0WG.png)

My goal is to be able to drop the FULL_NAME column, but I need these two split first and I am not sure why it is not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm kind of new to this, if you know of a way to help me I would really appreciate this. This is just on a test table.

Comment: I think I need an update query but I'm not sure of the syntax or how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `SELECT` statement only displays data. It does not change it. `ALTER TABLE` is a DDL command that would actually change the structure of the table (like add a column), but you have not told it what to do; it does not change data. Use `UPDATE` to change data values:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET
    FIRST_NAME = SUBSTR(FULL_NAME, 1, INSTR(FULL_NAME, ' ', 1, 1)-1),
    LAST_NAME = SUBSTR(FULL_NAME, INSTR(FULL_NAME, ' ', -1)+1);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: If you don't mind walking me through the structure of the update query real quick I would appreciate that. I can see it, but could you explain why its like that? Some examples I saw online had a "where" at the end instead of the commit. An explanation on that difference would help.

Comment: @Jr_23 a `where` clause would filter the rows that you apply the update to. You might only want to update one customer, or use some other filtering condition, instead of updating all of them. `commit` saves the changes.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification, it was insightful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generated columns:

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS
    ADD FIRST_NAME AS substr("FULL_NAME", 1, instr("FULL_NAME", ' ', 1, 1) - 1);

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS
    ADD LAST_NAME AS  substr("FULL_NAME", instr("FULL_NAME", ' ',(- 1)) + 1) ;
```

These are calculated when they are references so the values are always up-to-date.  No `UPDATE` is needed.

Note:  I strongly, strongly discourage you from using double quotes for column names.  There is no need for them.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a648cd2d9278a923abfa43be8e67ef8c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone has been very informative. I was wondering if it was possible to do while you setup the column, thanks for that as well.